# Add Security Group Claims to SAML token for Custom Azure Active Directory Application

Tags: azure, saml-2.0, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, kentor-authservices

I have added a custom application to our active directory per MS guide [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-custom-apps/)

How can I customise the claims provided in the SAML token to provide the security groups of the authenticated user. This article makes no mention of groups https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saml-claims-customization/

I know normally for an Azure application in AD I can alter the manifest to get it to return the security groups. However I have no experience with the SAML version. We have a very limited number of groups we care about so even boolean flag of InGroupA would work.

I am using kentor Authservices and that part is working fine but it has no claim for groups. I have attempted to make it require the attribute http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups however it still logs me in without token containing this claim.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check this article?
http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/

Comment: Yeah - I had read that. Custom Application added via Gallery doesn't offer ability to allow me to edit manifest so I don't seem to be able to make it return group claims this way. SAML token never contains groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible however you need to do it via the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)

Find the application via it's objectid
Update the property groupMembershipClaims to value All

You can also use this PowerShell script.

Using the script [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2013/12/27/aadgraphpowershell-a-powershell-client-for-windows-azure-ad-graph-api/) I loaded the needed libraries and then ran the following commands:

```
Connect-AAD (use the tenant GA credentials)
Execute-AADQuery -Base "applications" -HTTPVerb Get
Execute-AADQuery -Base "applications/<GUID>" -HTTPVerb Patch -Data (New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{"groupMembershipClaims"="All"})
```